# UIToolBar under navigationBar without toolbar moving on scroll

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitoolbar

I'm trying to add a toolBar under the navigationBar in a UITableViewController. This can easily be done by StoryBoard Builder, but when i scroll down or up it will scroll. My question is then how i can add a Toolbar under navigationBar without the toolBar moving on tableView Scroll?

illustration

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a table view controller. Use a simple view controller which has an explicit outlet to a table view which is a sub view. Then you can also have a sub view which is the toolbar above the table view (and anything else you might need above or below the table in future).

Alternatively you can set the tableHeaderView (and tableFooterView) of the table view itself.